# Roo command(run in roo-shell) that will push-in all the Roo-code to Java file

Tags: spring-roo

Is there a Roo command that will push-in all the Roo-code in .aj files of a project to Java files or that will remove Roo from the generated code(but retaining the functionality) of a project.
Kindly let me know as iam not able to find such a command in existing Roo documentation.
i could find only push-in menu option through The Refactor menu on a file or project.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I m adding this answer for future reference of others looking for this question.

From Spring Roo 2, a new command is introduced named **push-in** to convert the elements declared in the ITDs to its .java files.

It allows you to push in all the ITDs or ITDs specific to a package or a class in the project.

This shows how the ITDs related to an entity class is removed in a package

[image: This shows how the ITDs related to an entity class is removed in a package]

Please note annotations relevant to Roo will not be removed from this, You have to remove them manually.

Answer (score 1):

No. there isn't. Automatic push-in is available only from Aspectj eclipse plug-in.

You can do it by hand, moving the code form *.aj* file to *.java* and removing the method/property class prefix.

Example: To push-in the `Pet.isSendRemainders` to `Pet` (from *clinic.roo* example) copy method code from `Pet_Roo_JavaBean.aj`:

```
public boolean Pet.isSendReminders() {
    return this.sendReminders;
}
```

To `Pet.java`

```
public boolean isSendReminders() {
    return this.sendReminders;
}
```

After that, Spring-roo console regenerates `Pet_Roo_JavaBean.aj` without `Pet.isSendRemainders` method.

Answer (score 1):

Using IntelliJ, you can right click on the project, `refactor`->`push ITDs In...`